# ¿Cuál de estas 2 formas de acceder a un método de manera repetitiva es mejor?

Tags: java, object

Siempre tuve la duda entre si es mejor crear un `object` y entonces usar un método de ese objeto o no crear el objeto, ejemplos:

- Sin haber creado un objeto de la clase que devolvería `otroMetodo()`:

```
Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo().print(algo, "Hola");
Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo().print(algo, "¿Cómo");
Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo().print(algo, "Estás?");
```

- Con un objeto:

```
ClassDeOtroMetodo claseDeOtroMetodo = Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo();
claseDeOtroMetodo.print(algo, "Hola");
claseDeOtroMetodo.print(algo, "¿Cómo");
claseDeOtroMetodo.print(algo, "Estás?");
```

¿Hay mucha diferencia o es lo mismo?

Comment: En mi opinión habría que explicar qué significa "mejor". ¿Se refiere a en cuanto a rendimiento o en cuanto a concepto (validez en POO)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Principalmente depende de si la salida de los métodos van a ser la misma o no en las sucesivas llamadas. Si pueden variar, entonces es necesario hacer la primera. También depende de dónde definas `ClassDeOtroMetodo claseDeOtroMetodo;` en caso de un uso muy elevado de veces (es mejor fuera de un bucle que dentro, o como variable privada de la clase que como local de un método, etc).

Entrando en detalles:

```
Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo().print(algo, "Hola");
Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo().print(algo, "¿Cómo");
Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo().print(algo, "Estás?");
```

Estamos ejecutando a grandes rasgos (lo más costoso):

- `T1`: Llamar al método de `Sistema` llamado `algunMetodo()`. Devuelve la instancia de un objeto.
- `T2`: Llamar al método `otroMetodo()` de la instancia devuelta por la llamada anterior. Devuelve la instancia de un objeto.
- `T3`: Llamar al método `print()` de la instancia devuelta por la llamada anterior.

Esto se ve repetido tres veces `3·(T1 + T2 + T3) = 3·T1 + 3·T2 + 3·T3`. Los valores devueltos por un método no pueden ser optimizados, deben invocarse una y otra vez.

Almacenando el resultado de las dos primeras llamadas:

```
ClassDeOtroMetodo claseDeOtroMetodo = Sistema.algunMetodo().otroMetodo();
claseDeOtroMetodo.print(algo, "Hola");
claseDeOtroMetodo.print(algo, "¿Cómo");
claseDeOtroMetodo.print(algo, "Estás?");
```

Estamos haciendo en la primera línea `T1 + T2` y luego repetir tres veces `T3`: `T1 + T2 + 3·T3`.

Los tiempos de acceso a variables e instancias y las asignaciones son despreciables respecto al tiempo de llamada a métodos.

---

**Medidas empíricas**

He desarrollado esta pequeña prueba de concepto. En el código estoy haciendo un poco de trampas porque obtengo el valor de respuesta de `algunMetodo()` durante la ejecución del constructor, por eso las diferencias son tan pequeñas. Por norma general un método debe hacer algún tipo de tratamiento de sus parámetros o del estado de la clase para devolver un resultado.

```
class Sistema {
  ClassDeOtroMetodo salida = null;

  public Sistema() {
    salida = new ClassDeOtroMetodo();
  }
  ClassDeOtroMetodo algunMetodo() {
    return salida;
  }
}

class ClassDeOtroMetodo {
  long num = 0;
  void print(long n) {
    num += n;
  }
}

class prueba {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    long t1, t2, t3, t4, i = 0, max = 10000000;
    Sistema pruebas = new Sistema();
    t1 = System.nanoTime();
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      pruebas.algunMetodo().print(1);
      pruebas.algunMetodo().print(2);
      pruebas.algunMetodo().print(i);
    }
    t2 = System.nanoTime();
    ClassDeOtroMetodo temporal1 = pruebas.algunMetodo();
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      temporal1.print(1);
      temporal1.print(2);
      temporal1.print(i);
    }
    t3 = System.nanoTime();
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      ClassDeOtroMetodo temporal2 = pruebas.algunMetodo();
      temporal2.print(1);
      temporal2.print(2);
      temporal2.print(i);
    }
    t4 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("T1: " + (t2 - t1));
    System.out.println("T2: " + (t3 - t2));
    System.out.println("T3: " + (t4 - t3));
  }
}
```

Resultado de dos ejecuciones consecutivas:

```
redstar@nvidiastar:~$ java prueba ; java prueba
T1: 24835361
T2: 10742087
T3: 11362793
T1: 25489086
T2: 11132643
T3: 12097208
```

Como puede observarse hay una ganancia considerable entre usar la variable temporal, incluso teniéndola dentro del bucle (aunque se reduce ligeramente el rendimiento).

Answer (score 0):

Ninguna forma es mejor o peor, eso depende completamente de caso de uso y contexto. Además en ambas formas creas un objeto, la diferencia es si guardas la referencia en una variable o no.

Eso significa que no solamente tienes una diferencia en la forma, también tienes una ambigüedad en el tema si ambos códigos hacen lo mismo. ¿Por qué?

```
 public static ClassDeOtroMetodo otroMetodo();
```

Esto es la interfaz que devuelve el objeto con que trabajas.
Lo que no se sabe es, si este metodo te devuelve un `Singleton`, significando que siempre te garantizaría el mismo objeto con cada ejecución, o si el metodo te insta un nuevo objeto con cada llamada.

En el primer caso, tus códigos harían lo mismo, en el segundo caso no.

Quedó claro?